# Replacing numeric value and slash using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with replacing URL parameter.

Here is the code snippet:

```
getTitle() {
  const title = this.router.url.replace(/\D\//g, '');
  return title;
}
```

But it is only replacing numeric value. I need to replace `/` and some numeric value.

What I exactly want is when URL receives something like this `/project/1` it is should be only `project`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding in your regex.

First of all, the token `\D` actually capture everything that **isn't** a number. You are looking for `\d`. Maybe a typo in your question ?

Secondly, you are trying to capture specifically parts of your string that are a number followed by a / right now.

If you want to capture all instances of both, you need to make a group capture:

```
/[\d\/]/g
```

This should give you the result you want. You can find an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/YgMD61/1)

Comment: Thanks it's working well. I am confused with my regex.